# How to add space between ColumnSeries in a Flex/Flash ColumnChart?

Tags: flex3, charts

I am using the Flex ColumnChart with multiple ColumnSeries. I want to add space between the ColumnSeries bars/columns.

What do I mean? If you look at the [Adobe LiveDocs for ColumnChart](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_06.html), I have a chart similar to the 1st chart. I want to add margin/padding between the orange and green columns (not the months).

[image]

I've looked through the LiveDocs and I can't find anything on it.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to play around with y coordinate of second series. I wrote you an example how you can achieve to control the distance between several series. This is not perfect but hopefully shows you the right way how to do it ;)

http://pastie.org/3327210

[image]

Comment: feel free to accept the answer, otherwise I would show you the horizontal bar chart;)

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing mx.charts.series.ColumnSet worked perfectly for me (at least in 4.0 sdk)

```
public class TestColumnSet extends ColumnSet 
{                   
    public var intraSetMaxColumnWidth:Number = NaN;
    public var intraSetColumnWidthRatio:Number = NaN;

    override protected function customizeSeries(glyph:IChartElement,i:uint):void
    {
        super.customizeSeries(glyph, i);            
        var currentSeries:IColumn = IColumn(glyph);         

        if(!isNaN(intraSetColumnWidthRatio))
            currentSeries.columnWidthRatio = intraSetColumnWidthRatio;          
        if(!isNaN(intraSetMaxColumnWidth))
            currentSeries.maxColumnWidth = intraSetMaxColumnWidth;      
    }   
 }
```

used like that:

```
var cs:TestColumnSet = new TestColumnSet();
...
cs.intraSetColumnWidthRatio = cs.columnWidthRatio/cs.series.length*(1-desiredSpaceRatio);
```